# URL rewriting using .htaccess on codeigniter website

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

Presently, my URL is `http://www.example.com/index.php/leadsadmin/login`, and I would like to change it to `http://www.admin.example.com`.

I am using the codeigniter framework, and I tried to create a subsite like `admin.example.com` and mapped the path it to `h:\root\home\...\modules\leadsadmin`, but it did not work.

What could I do to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

Before answering, I have a doubt in your present URL
http:// www.mydomain.com/index.php/leadsadmin/login it might be http:// www.mydomain.com/leadsadmin/login

Ask your service provider to create subdomain admin.mydomain.com   and point it to webserver IP address

Then on apache virual host configuration add ServerAlias as follows

```
 ServerAlias admin.mydomain.com // Add this line to your virtual host block.
```

Comment: It is a codeignater URL and it serves like that only.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to remove index.php from url using .htaccess file

.htaccess file should be

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Then, in application/config/routes.php file, you need to write

```
switch ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) {
case 'www.admin.example.com':
    $route['default_controller'] = "leadsadmin/login";
break;

default:
    // default action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /your_project_name
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```